# Android database update is still not working after using all possible options

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to update my database table in Android application and I have tried almost every possible solutions I found on the internet. Here is my function where I am trying to update

```
public boolean updateBitcoinVerifier(){
        SQLiteDatabase dbWrite = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_BAV_ID, String.valueOf(1));
        values.put(KEY_BAV_VERIFIED, String.valueOf(1));

        String where = KEY_BAV_ID+"=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(1)};
        String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED + " SET "
                + KEY_BAV_VERIFIED + " = \"1\" WHERE " + KEY_BAV_ID + " = \"1\";";


        boolean success = true;

        try {
            //dbWrite.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
            dbWrite.beginTransaction();
            //dbWrite.update(TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED, values, where, whereArgs);
            dbWrite.execSQL(updateQuery);
            dbWrite.setTransactionSuccessful();
            dbWrite.endTransaction();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = false;
        } finally {
            dbWrite.close();
        }

        return success;
    }
```

So this table has only one row with two columns inside,

```
------------------
| ID | VERIFIED  |
------------------
| 1  |     0     |
------------------
```

What I am trying to do is update `verified` to `true` or `1` where `id` = `1` and as you can see in my codes, I have used both `update()` and `execSQL()` functions and it is still not updating it to true. It is still keeping verified to 0 as false. Can anyone tell me what to do?

This is how I am creating table in database,

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED
            + " (" + KEY_BAV_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_BAV_VERIFIED + " INTEGER);";

    //adding first and the only row in production database
    private static final String CREATE_DEFAULT_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED
            + " (" + KEY_BAV_ID + ", " + KEY_BAV_VERIFIED + ") " +
            "VALUES (\"1\", \"0\");";
```

And the function that I am using to get data from database is,

```
public BitcoinAddressValidatorModel getBitcoinAddressVerified(){
        BitcoinAddressValidatorModel validator = new BitcoinAddressValidatorModel();

        SQLiteDatabase dbRead = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED + " WHERE "
                + KEY_BAV_ID + " = 1;";

        Cursor c = dbRead.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        try {
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    System.out.println("=================");
                    System.out.println("-----------------");
                    System.out.println("=================");
                    System.out.println("-----------------");
                    System.out.println("=================");
                    System.out.println(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BAV_ID));
                    System.out.println(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BAV_VERIFIED));
                    System.out.println("-----------------");
                    System.out.println("=================");
                    System.out.println("-----------------");



                    validator.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BAV_ID)));
                    validator.setVerified(Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BAV_VERIFIED))));
                } while (c.moveToNext());

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                c.close();

            dbRead.close();
        }


        return validator;
    }
```

I added those `print` functions to verify what I am getting from database and it turns out I am getting `0 and 1` instead of `1 and 0` because i am printing `ID` first which should be `1` but it is not. So I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Why are you suppressing all exceptions? Remove all `catch`es.

Comment: I am using try catch so i can trace if there is an error while getting data from database or updating/inserting/deleting something in database.

Answer (score 0):

String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + TABLE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS_VERIFIED + " SET " + KEY_BAV_VERIFIED + " = 1 " WHERE " + KEY_BAV_ID + " = 1";

 you need not escape integer values. I have written queries in my last project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason that why I was always getting false. Because my boolean value stores data in integer filed in database and when I try to parse value using `Boolean.parseBoolean` it will check of data string is `true` or not. So if it is not `true` as a string, it doesn't matter if it is `1` or what else, it will always return `false` because string is not `true` itself.